# How to make xmodmap changes permanent?

Tags: systemd, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xmodmap

Using `xmodmap` to remap meta key with the following command:

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode 133 = F14'
```

How can i make the change permanent, especially on system sleep, resume and reboot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Reboot**

On the setting panel (KDE/GNOME) there is a startup section where application can be added to startup session, xmodmap can be added there

**Resume**

Xmodmap does not keep the changes after sleep/resume, here is how to set xmodmap on system resume with systemd: (non systemd user can [use this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup))

- Create xkeyboard resume script:

  `touch /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/xkeyboard; chmod 755 /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/xkeyboard`
- Edit xkeyboard and fill it with:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
    pre)
        exit 0
    ;;
    post)
        export DISPLAY=:0
        sleep 10
        xmodmap -e 'keycode 133 = F14'
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Can you explain why `export DISPLAY=:0` and `sleep 10` ?

Comment: Depending on the configuration this may be useful, this service is run as root by systemd, xmodmap apply the configuration to x (graphical interface) and thus `export DISPLAY=:0` permit to indicate that the setting is applied to display 0, this **may** be required if the current user is not root. As the service is called on resume after sleep, `sleep 10` is there to make sure everything is loaded, let say if you use an external bluetooth keyboard and the kernel module is not yet loaded or similar case, `sleep 10` will give it extra time to load before applying the settings.

Comment: Thanks! I ran into a few of those issues myself. In the end I wasted a bunch of time and could not get it to work.

Comment: What about when the keyboard itself disconnects? I have a bluetooth keyboard that "goes to sleep" on an idle time out presumably, and when it comes back, the xmodmap mapping is gone. I'm manually re-applying it at the moment.